# Problems connecting to Athena via R on Ubuntu server

Tags: java, r, ubuntu-18.04, amazon-athena

I am attempting to connect to Athena via an R script on an Ubuntu 18.04 server, but the script prints out an error once it reaches the row with the "dbConnect" function. It also freezes the console and doesn't accept any other commands besides stopping the whole process.

The code I'm using is:

```
library(DBI)
library(AWR.Athena)

Sys.setenv(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "my_id", AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "my_pwd")

con <- dbConnect(Athena(), region = "us-east-2", S3OutputLocation = "s3://aws-athena-query-results-xxxx-us-east-2/API+export", Schema = "default")   
sql <- dbGetQuery(con, sql_query)
```

The error I'm getting:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.simba.athena.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Strangely, the script prints out an error if I run it locally as well, but it does continue and execute successfully. Can anyone shed a light as to what might be the cause?

Comment: When you run this script on Ubuntu do you see any query id generated in Athena history.Can you confirm if the query is reaching Athena?

Comment: It's not reaching Athena at all.

Comment: Have you tried all steps as mentioned in https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/running-r-on-amazon-athena/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here. Setting java options
`options(java.parameters=c("-Dhttp.proxyHost=hostname", "-Dhttp.proxyPort=portnumber", "-Dhttps.proxyHost=hostname", "-Dhttps.proxyPort=portnumber"))`
fixed the issue.